# Best way of I18N support in HTML as well as JQuery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internationalization

I am developing a project where I am using HTML + JQuery. I tried using jquery.i18n.properties.js. However I find this more tedious. Is there any better way of doing this. I want to make sure :-

- The static content on my web page adheres to I18N.
- All the dynamic messages like warnings, errors and info messages to be as per I18N.

Thanks.

Comment: try moment : http://momentjs.com/

Comment: you should use a framework like angularjs, this simplify your life in this project :)

Comment: @IlyasMimouni, Firstly my project is something which doesnot involve any server calls. Also it ends up in  a single page. So I dont see the need of using Angular JS. Secondly, momentjs does not give me a way of Internationalizing my headings, titles and text's. Or may be I am not aware of how to do it. Need a simple solution rather than complicating the things.